# Can't use volume button to mute on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, mute

I've migrated my VoIP application to iOS7 recently, and there's an open bug still remaining which I can't understand.

When in VoIP call, in iOS6 you can push the physical volume button to lower the volume, down to Zero.

Now, in iOS7, I can lower the sound only down to the last step before zero, which means the volume cannot be muted.

I suspect this is something that's on iOS7 side, since I don't have the problem with the same IPA on an iOS6 device.

Anybody knows what's up?

Comment: Does the mute switch work ?

Comment: I have the same issue in my app.  The mute switch has no effect.  If the app allows multitasking, you can't mute while multitasking either.  Wish I knew how to correct the issue.

Comment: what is the version of ios7 used you..

Comment: Confirmed the issue on all versions of iOS7 available, 7.0.0->7.0.4 and 7.1 beta..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem with my VoIP app...

My Solution:
After everything is set up, set the category to Playback,

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

Then set it back to PlayAndRecord,

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```

This works for me, hope this helps someone who comes across the same problem.

Comment: This actually fixed the issue on my side as well. Thanks. For those interested, this is what you should do!

Comment: Future SO browsers be warned: this approach disables any VoiceProcessingIO (vpio) audio unit configuration in iOS 9, by switching to RemoteIO when you set the playback-only category: RemoteIO allows rocker-button muting, but vpio is where the onboard AEC lives. For VoIP apps, this workaround may have undesirable consequences.

Answer (score 3):

A bit old question, but I also needed a solution for Gui13's question/comment:

> We're not using any sort of control in our app, all volume interaction is based on volume buttons.. So I could maybe implement this but I'd need a way to tie it to the volume buttons. Is this possible?

Apple recommends using `MPVolumeView`, so I came up with this:

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [MPVolumeView new];
[self.view addSubview:volumeView];
```

and then:

```
__block UISlider *volumeSlider = nil;
[[volumeView subviews] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
        volumeSlider = obj;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
[volumeSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(handleVolumeChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

with:

```
- (void)handleVolumeChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s - %f", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ((UISlider *)sender).value);
}
```

The `[MPVolumeView new]` code above inits `MPVolumeView` with no frame so, it's not visible in our `self.view` where it has been added as a subview, but it is important that it has to be added!

You can also init the `MPVolumeView` with the code:

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
volumeView.showsRouteButton = NO;
volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = NO;
[self.view addSubview:volumeView];
```

which will also init the empty `MPVolumeView` (i.e. without RouteButton and VolumeSlider).

What's interesting is that `UISlider` subview (actually `MPVolumeSlider`, the subclass of `UISlider`) will still be found in the `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` above.

This approach is also interesting because you can save the reference to `volumeSlider` and use it later to set volume from code, or your custom control:

Init and add to your view:

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [MPVolumeView new];
volumeView.showsRouteButton = NO;
volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = NO;
[self.view addSubview:volumeView];
```

Find and save reference to `UISlider`:

```
__weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
[[volumeView subviews] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
        __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
        strongSelf.volumeSlider = obj;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```

Add target action for `UIControlEventValueChanged`:

```
[self.volumeSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(handleVolumeChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And then update your custom control when the volume has been changed (i.e. by the hardware volume controls):

```
- (void)handleVolumeChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s - %f", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, self.volumeSlider.value);
    self.myCustomVolumeSliderView.value = self.volumeSlider.value;
}
```

and also:

```
- (IBAction)myCustomVolumeSliderViewValueChanged:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"set volume to: %f", self.myCustomVolumeSliderView.value);
    self.volumeSlider.value = self.myCustomVolumeSliderView.value;
}
```

Hope this helps someone (and that Apple doesn't remove MPVolumeSlider from MPVolumeView).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use applicationMusicPlayer instead of iPodMusicPlayer to set the system volume:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
musicPlayer.volume = 1; // max volume
musicPlayer.volume = 0; // min volume (mute)
musicPlayer.volume = 0.0625; // 1 bar on the overlay volume display
```

Apple is assuming that they know each and every way in which a volume will need to be administered.

There are, in fact, occasions when we want to change how the volume is controlled without forcing the user to have a volume slider on the screen, (alarm clocks and media players come to mind immediately).
Yuou can take reference

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/controlling-system-output-volume-with-the-mpvolumeview-class-part-one/

Comment: We're not using any sort of control in our app, all volume interaction is based on volume buttons.. So I could maybe implement this but I'd need a way to tie it to the volume buttons. Is this possible?

Comment: I'll give you the bounty since this is the closest to a solution I've seen. But this isn't the solution I was looking for..